# Pyramid Shaped Pattern in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to solve the below question:

Write a program that prints out lines of stars, based on the values determined by the user-input.The program should print the number of stars that increases on each line from the minimum number until it
reaches the maximum number, and then decreases until it goes back to the minimum number.

For this question I am using Python and below is my code:

```
def full_shape(a,b):
    rows=((b-a)+1)
    for i in range(rows):
        print(' '*(rows-i-1)+'* '*(i+a))
    for j in range(rows-1,0,-1):
        print(' '*(rows-j-1)+'* '*(j+a))
```

When I call the function, I'm getting the below output:

[image: a busy cat]

Whereas the output is supposed to be like the image below:

[image: a busy cat]

Can someone help me to understand why I'm not getting the expected pattern shape?

Thank you

Comment: Your output and the expected output did not make it into the question.  Could you edit the question and add those in?

Comment: Hi Hoog,
Just amended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second range should be range(rows-2, -1, -1).

It's because range(x) produces numbers from 0 to x-1. It's the same as range(0, x, 1). Similar is range(x, y, -1) which produces numbers from x to y+1.

Answer (score 0):

here is an edit to your function:

```
def full_shape(a,b):
    rows=b-a+1
    for i in range(rows):
        print(' '*(rows-i-1)+'* '*(i+a))
    for j in range(rows-2,-1,-1):
        print(' '*(rows-j-1)+'* '*(j+a))
```

Just in case you need another way of doing this:

```
def diamond(a,b):
    c = [(('*'+' ')*i).center(2*b) for i in range(a,b+1)]
    print('\n'.join(c[:-1]+c[::-1]))
```

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your feedback. I tried using your code and it worked when I set the input as (1,5). However it wasn't working for larger inputs like (5,7)

I'm trying to resolve that bit now